# Magento - Default vs. Primary Shipping Address

Tags: magento

If I load a customer in the following way:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->load($customer_id);
```

Whats the difference between:

```
$customer -> getDefaultShippingAddress();
```

and

```
$customer -> getPrimaryShippingAddress();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They return the same result

See /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

```
 /*
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Address
 */
public function getPrimaryBillingAddress()
{
    return $this->getPrimaryAddress('default_billing');
}

/**
 * Get customer default billing address
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Address
 */
public function getDefaultBillingAddress()
{
    return $this->getPrimaryBillingAddress();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing because getDefaultShippingAddress() calls internally getPrimaryShippingAddress(). You can check the code yourself in /app/code/local/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php

```
/**
 * Get default customer shipping address
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Address
 */
public function getPrimaryShippingAddress()
{
    return $this->getPrimaryAddress('default_shipping');
}

/**
 * Get default customer shipping address
 *
 * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Address
 */
public function getDefaultShippingAddress()
{
    return $this->getPrimaryShippingAddress();
}
```